# Combine two tables only when 3 similar values using pandas python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I need to combine two different data sets only when 3 columns have the same value, for example:

df1

```
    iso3_o    iso3_d    year   value1   value2
      pak       tza     2000      123      456
      lby       vnm     2000      435      148
      can       jpn     2001      983      095
      civ       pa      2001      109      265
      bol       slv     2004      019      239
```

df2

```
     origin   target    year  value_3  value_4
      pak       tza     2000      763      987
      lby       vnm     2001      349      274
      can       jpn     2002      238      095
      chl       geo     2000      109      236
      bol       slv     2004      047      384
```

So, to combine the tables the values need to satisfy the following conditions:

```
df1['iso3_o'] == df2['origins'] AND df1['iso3_d'] == df2['target'] AND df1['year'] == df2['year']
```

As I result I need to get a combine table as follows:

```
iso3_o    iso3_d    year   value1   value2   value_3   value_4
   pak       tza     2000      123     456       763       987
   lby       vnm     2000      435     148       NaN       NaN
   lby       vnm     2001      NaN     NaN       349       274
   can       jpn     2001      983     095       NaN       NaN    
   can       jpn     2002      NaN     NaN       238       095    
   civ       pa      2001      109     265       NaN       NaN
   bol       slv     2004      019     239       047       384
   chl       geo     2000      NaN     NaN       109       236
```

Answer (score 3):

IIUC we can rename columns in one DF so that we have the same column names for "joining" columns in both DFs. [DataFrame.merge()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) will merge `on the intersection of the columns by default`:

```
In [114]: df1.merge(df2.rename(columns={'origin':'iso3_o', 'target':'iso3_d'}), how='outer')
Out[114]:
  iso3_o iso3_d  year  value1  value2  value_3  value_4
0    pak    tza  2000   123.0   456.0    763.0    987.0
1    lby    vnm  2000   435.0   148.0      NaN      NaN
2    can    jpn  2001   983.0    95.0      NaN      NaN
3    civ     pa  2001   109.0   265.0      NaN      NaN
4    bol    slv  2004    19.0   239.0     47.0    384.0
5    lby    vnm  2001     NaN     NaN    349.0    274.0
6    can    jpn  2002     NaN     NaN    238.0     95.0
7    chl    geo  2000     NaN     NaN    109.0    236.0
```

Comment: the script is duplicating the rows =(.